# Binding multiple polygons in R

Tags: r, rgdal, ggplot2

I have a directory that contains around 700 .shp files. I want to create a map in R that displays all of them. The easiest way i could think to do this was to bind them all together and then use ggplot2 to create a map. here is my code to read the files and create a list containing the files:

```
dir <- "./Basins/separate_basins/"
basins <- list.files(dir, pattern = "\\.shp$")
basins <- unique(file_path_sans_ext(basins))
cord <- "+init=epsg:2163"
templist <- list()

for (i in basins){ 

  thisbasin <- readOGR(dsn=dir, layer=i)
  thisbasin <- spTransform(thisbasin, cord)
  templist[[i]] <- data.frame(thisbasin)
}
```

I then try to use the bind function to bind all of the components in the list together: 
    `test_bind <- bind(templist)`
Then I tried to test if this works using 
    `plot(test_bind)
but it prints like this:
[image]

I want to display the polygons that are present in the original .shp files. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is coercing the data into a data.frame before piping into the list object so, don't do that. I would recommend some small changes to your code and then using `do.call` on the list to bind the results into a single sp SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object.

```
templist <- list() 
  for (i in 1:length(basins)){ 
    thisbasin <- readOGR(dsn=dir, layer=basins[i])
    templist[[i]] <- spTransform(thisbasin, cord)
  }
basins <- do.call("rbind", templist)
```

At this point, since you want to plot using ggplot2, I would recommend coercing to an sf object.

Comment: BTW if you go to sf best to start with sf  x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(dir, pattern = "shp$", full.names = TRUE), sf::read_sf))  - will be faster, no need for dropping .shp etc.